# Integrating $1/\theta$ over a range

Tags: calculus

My textbook is telling me:

$$\int_{x}^{1} \frac{1}{\theta} d\theta = {|\log x|}$$

While I arrive at:

$$\int_{x}^{1} \frac{1}{\theta} d\theta = |\log(1)| - {|\log(x)|} = - {|\log(x)|}$$

Why am I wrong?

$0 < x < 1$

Edit: Here is a pic from the textbook

[image]

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: I am pretty sure that's a typo. A correct formula is $$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\log\left|x\right|+C,$$which is valid on any open interval contained in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @Yanko that was a copy mistake, the answers do depend on X. I updated. I understand the integral needs to be positive but I don't understand where my logic breaks down in the steps I added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer in the book is not wrong but is over-complicated.

The integral of $1/\theta$ in the positive real line is $\ln(\theta)$. Therefore

$$\int_x^1 1/\theta d\theta = \ln(1)-\ln(x)= -\ln(x)$$

However since $0<x<1$ (I suppose) we have that $\ln(x)$ is negative and so $-\ln(x) = |\ln(x)|$

Comment: Is the book just doing that to show that the resut can't be negative? In this case it's a probability so that would make sense.

Comment: @Juicy It could be

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that the antiderivative of $\dfrac 1x$ is not $|\log x|$ but $\log x$. Then

$$\int_x^1\frac{dx}x=\log 1-\log x=-\log x$$ and in the particular case that $\log x <0$, this is also $|\log x|$.

---

The traditional solution is

$$\int_a^b\frac{dx}x=\log|b|-\log|a|.$$

I claim that it is technically more correct to write

$$\int_a^b\frac{dx}x=\log\frac ba.$$